# The correct formatting of Mysql time

Tags: php, mysql

I want to save the time in the Mysql database. I wrote a script that generates time. 
**I have a problem with the correct generation of time**

```
<?php
$durs = array(
    '3:56',
    '1:11:00',
    '2:04:56'
);

foreach ($durs as $dur){
    echo date('H:i:s', strtotime($dur)).'<br>';
}
?>
```

**The above example displays date in the form 03:56:00 instead of 00:03:56.**

Comment: I'd probably suggest checking the formatting of the string before you generate the time. If there's only 1 colon, add '00:' to the left of the string. If there's 2 colons, you're good to go.

Comment: Is there a function for counting characters in the string? beside echo count(explode(':', $date))-1;

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php

Answer (score 0):

StrToTime is expecting a h:i:s format and you are sending only 2 numbers on your fist array element
 you need to reformat your array as:

```
<?php
$durs = array(
    '0:3:56',
    '1:11:00',
    '2:04:56'
);

foreach ($durs as $dur){
    echo date('H:i:s', strtotime($dur)).'<br>';
}
```

Or you need to implement a function that first verifies what type of value is stored on the array and then send it to the correct format in timetostring